# Delay of loading of cached WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webresource.axd

I am seeing some strange behavior that does not make much sense to me. Basically I have a web page that takes around 1.5seconds to load. However, 0.5 seconds of that time there is a delay before a WebResource.axd file is loaded. This contains just a few styles related to a Telerik Rad Editor. I am curious if anyone would know why there would be this 0.5 second delay before the WebResource.axd was loaded. I can see it is retrieving from the browser cache.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the markup that you are seeing this delay on?  Are you using the StylesheetManager?

Comment: Not using the StylesheetManager - I added a screen shot from HttpWatch for some more clarity.